# How to match start or end of given string using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to match a string which starts or ends with a "test" using regex in java.

Match Start of the string:-
      String a = "testsample";

```
  String pattern = "^test";

  // Create a Pattern object
  Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

  // Now create matcher object.
  Matcher m = r.matcher(a);
```

Match End of the string:-
      String a = "sampletest";

```
  String pattern = "test$";

  // Create a Pattern object
  Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

  // Now create matcher object.
  Matcher m = r.matcher(a);
```

How can I combine regex for starts or ends with a given string ?

Answer (score 18):

Just use regex alternation operator `|`.

```
String pattern = "^test|test$";
```

In `matches` method, it would be,

```
string.matches("test.*|.*test");
```

Comment: Is there a way to use "test" string at once in regex or inside matches method

Answer (score 3):

use this code

```
String string = "test";
String pattern = "^" + string+"|"+string+"$";

// Create a Pattern object
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

// Now create matcher object.
Matcher m = r.matcher(a);
```

Comment: This is the same solution as @AvinashRaj

Comment: I did, and you are proposing the same regex.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can build a dynamic regex that you can use both with `Matcher#find()` and `Matcher#matches()`:

```
String a = "testsample";
String word = "test";
String pattern = "(?s)^(" + Pattern.quote(word) + ".*$|.*" + Pattern.quote(word) + ")$";
// Create a Pattern object
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
// Now create matcher object.
Matcher m = r.matcher(a);
if (m.find()){
    System.out.println("true - found with Matcher"); 
} 
// Now, the same pattern with String#matches:
System.out.println(a.matches(pattern));
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/vw6zsp)

The `pattern` will look like `^(\Qtest\E.*$|.*\Qtest\E)$` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lR1pK3/1)) since the `word` is searched for as a sequence of literal characters (this is achieved with `Pattern.quote`). The `^` and `$` that are not necessary for `matches` are necessary for `find` (and they do not prevent `matches` from matching, either, thus, do not do any harm).

Also, note the `(?s)` DOTALL inline modifier that makes a `.` match any character *including* a newline.